# Is there a way to specify a range of valid values for a function argument with type hinting in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I am a big fan of the type hinting in python, however I am curious if there is a way to specify a valid range of values for a given parameter using type hinting.

What I had in mind is something like

```
from typing import *

def function(
        number: Union[float, int],
        fraction: Float[0.0, 1.0] = 0.5 # give a hint that this should be between 0 and 1,
):
    return fraction * number
```

I can imagine one can enforce this with an assertion, or perhaps specify what the valid range of values is within the docstring, but it feels like having something like Float[0.0, 1.0] would look more elegant.

Comment: An obvious solution would be to subclass `Float` with a more specific type which rejects values which are outside the allowed range.

Comment: @tripleee That sounds like an interesting proposal. Could you post a rough sample of how that might look like?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Python 3.9 introduced [`typing.Annotated`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Annotated):

```
In [75]: from typing import *

In [76]: from dataclasses import dataclass

In [77]: @dataclass
    ...: class ValueRange:
    ...:     min: float
    ...:     max: float
    ...:

In [78]: def function(
    ...:         number: Union[float, int],
    ...:         fraction: Annotated[float, ValueRange(0.0, 1.0)] = 0.5
    ...: ):
    ...:     return fraction * number
    ...:
```

Like any other type hint it does not perform any runtime checks:

```
In [79]: function(1, 2)
Out[79]: 2
```

However you can implement your own runtime checks. The code below is just an example, it does not cover all cases and probably an overkill for your simple function:

```
In [88]: import inspect

In [89]: @dataclass
    ...: class ValueRange:
    ...:     min: float
    ...:     max: float
    ...:
    ...:     def validate_value(self, x):
    ...:         if not (self.min <= x <= self.max):
    ...:             raise ValueError(f'{x} must be in range [{self.min}, {self.max}]')
    ...:

In [90]: def check_annotated(func):
    ...:     hints = get_type_hints(func, include_extras=True)
    ...:     spec = inspect.getfullargspec(func)
    ...:
    ...:     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    ...:         for idx, arg_name in enumerate(spec[0]):
    ...:             hint = hints.get(arg_name)
    ...:             validators = getattr(hint, '__metadata__', None)
    ...:             if not validators:
    ...:                 continue
    ...:             for validator in validators:
    ...:                 validator.validate_value(args[idx])
    ...:
    ...:         return func(*args, **kwargs)
    ...:     return wrapper
    ...:
    ...:

In [91]: @check_annotated
    ...: def function_2(
    ...:         number: Union[float, int],
    ...:         fraction: Annotated[float, ValueRange(0.0, 1.0)] = 0.5
    ...: ):
    ...:     return fraction * number
    ...:
    ...:

In [92]: function_2(1, 2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-c9345023c025> in <module>
----> 1 function_2(1, 2)

<ipython-input-90-01115cb628ba> in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     10                 continue
     11             for validator in validators:
---> 12                 validator.validate_value(args[idx])
     13
     14         return func(*args, **kwargs)

<ipython-input-87-7f4ac07379f9> in validate_value(self, x)
      6     def validate_value(self, x):
      7         if not (self.min <= x <= self.max):
----> 8             raise ValueError(f'{x} must be in range [{self.min}, {self.max}]')
      9

ValueError: 2 must be in range [0.0, 1.0]

In [93]: function_2(1, 1)
Out[93]: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can and you don't mind using third-party packages, [Pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) provides [Constrained Types](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#constrained-types). For your specific example, one of the constrained types is [`confloat`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#arguments-to-confloat) with the following parameters:

> - `ge: float = None`: enforces float to be greater than or equal to the set value
> - `lt: float = None`: enforces float to be less than the set value

```
In [35]: from pydantic import confloat

In [36]: def function(
    ...:     number: Union[float, int],
    ...:     fraction: confloat(ge=0.0, le=1.0) = 0.5,
    ...: ) -> float:
    ...:     return fraction * number
```

If only used as a type hint, it doesn't enforce it at runtime:

```
In [38]: function(1, 0)
Out[38]: 0

In [39]: function(1, 1.0)
Out[39]: 1.0

In [40]: function(1, 15)
Out[40]: 15
```

But you can use Pydantic's [`validate_arguments`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validation_decorator/) decorator which:

> allows the arguments passed to a function to be parsed and validated using the function's annotations before the function is called

```
In [41]: from pydantic import confloat, validate_arguments

In [42]: @validate_arguments
    ...: def function(
    ...:     number: Union[float, int],
    ...:     fraction: confloat(ge=0.0, le=1.0) = 0.5,
    ...: ) -> float:
    ...:     return fraction * number
    ...: 

In [43]: function(1, 0)
Out[43]: 0.0

In [44]: function(1, 1.0)
Out[44]: 1.0

In [45]: function(1, 0.37)
Out[45]: 0.37

In [46]: function(1, 15)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [46], line 1
----> 1 function(1, 15)

...
ValidationError: 1 validation error for Function
fraction
  ensure this value is less than or equal to 1.0 (type=value_error.number.not_le; limit_value=1.0)
```

See the [ConstrainedTypes](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#constrained-types) section for more `con*` variations.